# Error running sampler with http request- Jmeter

Tags: apache, http, jmeter

I am running sampler (HTTP Request ) with the settings:

```
Server Name or IP:  localhost:8044/ca
Path: /
```

Its failing and throwing the error message:

> ```
> Thread Name: LoadTest 1-1
> Sample Start: 2017-02-01 16:50:41 GMT+05:30
> Load time: 0
> Connect Time: 0
> Latency: 0
> Size in bytes: 1077
> Headers size in bytes: 0
> Body size in bytes: 1077
> Sample Count: 1
> Error Count: 1
> Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
> Response message: Non HTTP response message: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 22: http://[localhost:8044/ca]/
> ```

Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be having the **Path** in "Server Name" input field, you have 2 options:

1. Split server name, port and path into 3 different inputs:

   [image: HTTP Request server name path]
2. Put the whole URL into "Path" input

   [image: HTTP Request URL in Path]

Few more tips:

- [Recording your test scenario using JMeter's built-in proxy server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) may be faster and easier
- Having Load Generator (JMeter) and Application Under Test on the same machine is not recommended, I would suggest running JMeter on another host, this way you will be able to avoid mutual interference in terms of using machine resources (JMeter is very resource intensive when it comes to conducting high loads)